# Sort array using custom sort order, one value is last

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort a multi dimensional array, and have one value always at the end of the array. The array should be sorted by 'unitText' (dont care how unitID is sorted), but always have "Last" as the last value in the array. I've almost got it, but not quite there.

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    /*
    $a = preg_replace('@^(Last) @', '', $a);
    $b = preg_replace('@^(Last) @', '', $b);
    return strcasecmp($a, $b);
    */

    if(strtolower(substr($a['unitText'],0,4))=="last") return strnatcmp($a['unitText'],9999);
    else if(strtolower(substr($b['unitText'],0,4))=="last") return strnatcmp(9999,$b['unitText']);
    else return strnatcmp($a, $b);

    //return strnatcmp($a['unitText'], $b['unitText']);

    //return end($a) > end($b);

}

$unit = array(
    array("unitID"=>80, "unitText"=>"Q701"),
    array("unitID"=>30, "unitText"=>"H568"),
    array("unitID"=>25, "unitText"=>"Last"),
    array("unitID"=>40, "unitText"=>"Z255"),
    array("unitID"=>20, "unitText"=>"A459")
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($unit);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<hr/>";

//uksort($unit['unitText'], "cmp");
//array_multisort($unit['unitText'], SORT_DESC, $unit['unitID'], SORT_ASC, $unit);
usort($unit, 'cmp');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($unit);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Should end up with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [unitID] => 20
            [unitText] => A459
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [unitID] => 30
            [unitText] => H568
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [unitID] => 80
            [unitText] => Q701
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [unitID] => 40
            [unitText] => Z255
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [unitID] => 25
            [unitText] => Last
        )

)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
else return strnatcmp($a, $b);
```

Remember that `$a` and `$b` are both arrays, but `strnatcmp()` compares strings. When this function is called, your two arrays will be implicitly cast to strings, which will both have the value of `Array`, so they will return as equal and will not be sorted.

You should be comparing the `unitText` value:

```
else return strnatcmp($a['unitText'], $b['unitText'])
```

The fact that you didn't see this tells me that you don't have your `error_reporting` level set high enough in development, since that implicit cast issues an `E_NOTICE` when it occurs. In development, you should always have `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` set (either at the entry point for your code, or in your `php.ini`, etc.) so that any little issues get immediately flagged for you to fix.

Also, there is no reason why you should be calling `strnatcmp()` at all when one of the values is 'Last', because you already know that the value should be last. Just return `1` or `-1` (depending on which contains 'Last') and be done with it.

Finally, you don't need all the `else` conditions in the code. Since all paths issue a `return`, you can assume that anything that comes after an `if` block is only executed if the comparison fails:

```
if (strtolower(substr($a['unitText'],0,4))=="last") {
  return 1;
}

if strtolower(substr($b['unitText'],0,4))=="last") {
  return -1;
}

return strnatcmp($a['unitText'], $b['unitText']);
```

In the above, the second `if` only executes if we didn't find 'Last' within `$a`, since the function would have already ended if it had. Similarly, the final `return` statement (with the `strnatcmp()` call) only executes if neither of the above `if` conditions passed, because either one of them would have returned a value and ended the function.

It's a little thing, but nesting a bunch of unneeded `if` and `else` blocks makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison at the end compares a and b which are both arrays.  I get the PHP warning:

PHP [Warning] strnatcmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

All of the comparisons could be simplified like so:

```
if(strtolower(substr($a['unitText'],0,4))=="last") return 1;
else if(strtolower(substr($b['unitText'],0,4))=="last") return -1;
else return strnatcmp($a['unitText'], $b['unitText']);
```

You only need to return zero, greater than or less than zero for the usort.